# Qt 5.6.0 Online installer not working

Tags: qt, qt-installer

Just did a fresh install of windows 10 and I'm attempting to install QT 5.6.0 I'm currently unable to log into the online install I get the following

Error Error downloading https://login.qt.io/api/qcl - server replied: REQUEST_TIMEOUT

I'm also unable to log into the main site, the sign in page is not responding, is any one currently experiencing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Site is down. I have tested it also with:

http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/login.qt.io.html

I think you should wait until tomorrow.